# install mysql on Windows Azure via Worker Role

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-worker-roles

I have created a worker role with following WorkerRole element in ServiceDefinition file. I have copied whole C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5 folder to a folder directly under worker role folder which its name is mysql when I run cspack and csrun it starts the emulator but it starts and stops the role, it does not work sometimes it says access denied for odbs@localhost but. thanks for your help

```
<WorkerRole enableNativeCodeExecution="true" name="MyPhpProj_MyWorkerRole" vmsize="Small">
<LocalStorage name="E2EStorage" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" />
<Endpoints>
  <InternalEndpoint name="PeerEndpointIn" protocol="tcp" />
  <InternalEndpoint name="MasterElectionService" protocol="tcp" />
  <InternalEndpoint name="MySQL" protocol="tcp" />
  <InternalEndpoint name="InstanceManagerEndpontIn" protocol="tcp" />
</Endpoints>
<Runtime executionContext="limited">
  <EntryPoint>
    <ProgramEntryPoint commandLine="./mysql/bin/mysql.exe" setReadyOnProcessStart="true" />
  </EntryPoint>
</Runtime>
<Imports/>
<LocalResources>
  <LocalStorage cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" name="MySQL" sizeInMB="260"/>
  <LocalStorage cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" name="MySQLDatastore" sizeInMB="20"/>
</LocalResources>
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="InitFile"/>
  <Setting name="LogLevel"/>
  <Setting name="ScheduledTransferPeriodInSeconds"/>
  <Setting name="WindowsAzureStorageConnectionString"/>
</ConfigurationSettings>
</WorkerRole>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is random like works sometime and not working other that I really don't know what is happening as it should not happen. IF there is some configuration or access issues, the problem will always the same.

When I ran MySQL  in my worker role I had a batch script in which I added a new User with Administrator privilege, and started MySql under that user privilege access so

I would used **Elevated**  with ProgramEntryPoint as below:

```
 <Runtime executionContext="elevated">
  <EntryPoint>
    <ProgramEntryPoint commandLine="./mysql/bin/mysql.exe" setReadyOnProcessStart="true" />
  </EntryPoint>
 </Runtime>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, So you think that what I have done is right. I could make it work at all I just wanted to say that it sometimes generates error. I only wanted to make sure that what I have done to install MySql on WA is right.?

Comment: Yes, you have done pretty much all correctly. You can also RDP to your instance and then verify that your MySql instance is running and can you run the same script to validate the connection.

Comment: I gave up to use EntryPoint and Mysql.exe because I got same error (odbc access denied) always, and I don't know how I create the batch file you talked about. Instead I used eclipse to create a worker role with a dll and I add entrypoint to that dll in cspack command. now when I go to Compute Emulator it shows green and following Copying folder mysql\data to C:/Users/ksaleh.CORP/AppData/Local/dftmp/Resources/60df05e6-005a-46ac-ae22-eedb22f178cc/directory/MySQLDatastore/
Information: MySQLIP=127.255.0.0
Information: MySQLPort=20000
information: working; 
How do I connect this mysql server?